# Flutter How to Cache Storage

Tags: flutter, dart

I am implementing the flutter chat app using CachedNetworkImage.

I want to remove the image cache of the chat room when I leave the chat room.

With DefaultCacheManager().emptyCache(), all caches are cleared and unavailable

also
The DefaultCacheManager().removeFile(key) is disabled because only a single cache image is erased.

Please help me

Comment: you could try storing cache for a particular chat room id and try to clear that storage path. It's just a vague idea but might be possible.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: added answer for example. You can generate a unique key for each chat room and then clear that cache I think

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
To clear the cache, use the DefaultCacheManager().removeFile(ChatIDkey)
Can I use it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: just give it a try or look into the class implementations. You might find something

Comment: Is it resolved?

Comment: I applied it in the method below, and it can be implemented similarly with the desired logic, but when looking up the cache folder,

// These three are intentionally made

 Directory: '/data/user/0/com.test/cache/chatProfile',
 File: '/data/user/0/com.test/cache/chatProfile/11111111@gmail.com.json',
 File: '/data/user/0/com.test/cache/chatProfile/22222222@gmail.com.json',

Comment: // I don't know why it's here

 Directory: '/data/user/0/com.test/cache/libCachedImageData',
 File: '/data/user/0/com.test/cache/libCachedImageData/e70e3eb0-ba3b-11ec-94c2-c52a24950368.jpg',
 Directory: '/data/user/0/com.test/cache/11111111@gmail.com',
 Directory: '/data/user/0/com.test/cache/22222222@gmail.com',

Comment: I organized it like this       Config(
          key,
          repo: JsonCacheInfoRepository(path: '$CachePath/chatProfile/$key.json')
      ),

Comment: so is the issue resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs written [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager):

The cache manager is customizable by creating a new CacheManager. It is very important to not create more than 1 CacheManager instance with the same key as these bite each other. In the example down here the manager is created as a Singleton, but you could also use for example Provider to Provide a CacheManager on the top level of your app. Below is an example with other settings for the maximum age of files, maximum number of objects and a custom FileService. The key parameter in the constructor is mandatory, all other variables are optional.

```
class CustomCacheManager {
  static const key = 'customCacheKey';
  static CacheManager instance = CacheManager(
    Config(
      key,
      stalePeriod: const Duration(days: 7),
      maxNrOfCacheObjects: 20,
      repo: JsonCacheInfoRepository(databaseName: key),
      fileSystem: IOFileSystem(key),
      fileService: HttpFileService(),
    ),
  );
}
```